# JBoss HelloWorld appilcation doesn't start

Tags: java, jboss7.x

Hi,

I'm trying to start JBoss example application 'jboss-as-helloworld'. 
And got such exception:

```
16:23:51,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting deployment of "jboss-as-helloworld.war"
16:23:51,176 INFO  [org.jboss.weld] (MSC service thread 1-5) Processing CDI deployment: jboss-as-helloworld.war
16:23:51,178 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jboss-as-helloworld.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jboss-as-helloworld.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "jboss-as-helloworld.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [:1.7.0_02]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [:1.7.0_02]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0_02]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.app.jboss-as-helloworld is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:560)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2194)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2194)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:307)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.naming.ApplicationContextProcessor.deploy(ApplicationContextProcessor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115)
    ... 5 more

16:23:51,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment of "jboss-as-helloworld.war" was rolled back with failure message {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jboss-as-helloworld.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jboss-as-helloworld.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"jboss-as-helloworld.war\""}}
16:23:51,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Stopped deployment jboss-as-helloworld.war in 10ms
16:23:51,192 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jboss-as-helloworld.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jboss-as-helloworld.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"jboss-as-helloworld.war\""}}}}
```

JBoss 7.0 Runtime Server has started and I can access JBoss start page `http://localhost:8080` and JBoss console.

I didn't change any code or xml, everything is default.
Tell me if it is need to provide additional info to investigate this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error, it looks like "Hello world" already deployed on the server (perhaps you selected to install examples):

```
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.app.jboss-as-helloworld is already registered
```

Try undeploy this app and then deploy again. Or you could rename your first "hello world" app and deploy - so there is no name conflict.

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps I followed to resolve the issue.

1. Stop the Server.
2. Go to deployment path.
3. Manually deleted the existing project in deployment folder.
4. Restarted the server
5. Deployed the application again.